# NSE in dplyr: nesting functions inside mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

While an avid fan of dplyr, I'm still puzzled by some of the NSE issues that inevitably arise when I try to do something of non-trivial complexity.

Case in point: finding row sums of a subset of columns.

```
temp <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 8:10)
```

This works:

```
temp %>% {rowSums(select(., B:C), na.rm = TRUE)}
```

and this (SE version) works:

```
temp %>% mutate(Sum = rowSums(select_(., .dots = "B:C"), na.rm = TRUE))
```

but this does not work:

```
temp %>% mutate(Sum = rowSums(select(., B:C), na.rm = TRUE))

Error: Position must be between 0 and n
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 4:6:8:10 : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In 4:6:8:10 : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

Why?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows#readme